# How can I overlay a div over another?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to have this dropdown menu overlay the main div as it's stuck behind it.

drop down menu code:

```
 `<div id="navbar-wrap" class="animated fadeInLeftBig">
  <nav>
    <ul> 
        <li><button> N/A </button></li>
        <li><button> N/A </button></li>
        <li><button> N/A </button></li>
        <li><button> N/A </button></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <li><button class="dropbtn">Recruitment</button></li>
        <div class="drop-content">
            <a href="#"> Apply Now! </a>
            <a href="#"> Our Team </a>
            <a href="#"> About Us </a>
            <a href="#"> Contact Us </a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>`
```

dropdown styling:

```
`dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.drop-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
min-width: 160px;
z-index: 5 !important;
}`
```

main div code:

```
   `<div id="main-wrap" class="animated fadeIn">
    <main>
    <h1 id="title-one"> Recruitment <h1>
    <p>  </p>
    <img src="interview.jpeg" alt="recruitment" id="img-one"/>
    </main>
    </div>`
```

not sure why it's appearing in front of the main div.

Comment: z-index to dropdown its parent

Comment: @TemaniAfif what do you mean?

Comment: i mean move the z-index to the parent element `.dropdow`